# It seems extremely expensive when storing struct type

Tags: solidity, contract-development, dapp-development, testnets

In my contract, there is a struct type:

```
struct Claim {
    address healthcareProvider;
    uint amount;
    bool patientSig;
    bool paid;
    uint item;
}
```

And the initialize function is:

```
function MakeClaim(uint _amount, uint _item, uint num) {
    Claim memory c;
    c.healthcareProvider = tx.origin;
    c.patientSig = false;
    c.paid = false;
    c.amount = _amount;
    c.item = _item;
}
```

When I call this function to create a new Claim type, I find the price is 2.687 ETH (not gas). This is much more than the cost for deploying the entire contract! I am testing it on the Morden test net. Where is my problem?

Comment: This function stores some arguments into `memory`, this is pretty cheap operation for the struct (tens of gas) comparing to storing data in `storage` (thousands of gas). Please measure operation/transaction costs in GAS, not in ETH. Maybe you gas price is too high?

Answer (score 1):

As in blockchain data-store is a scarce resource, it's pretty expensive.
Storing data is the most expensive operation in any smart contract.

```
sstore  100     Paid for a normal SSTORE operation (doubled or waived sometimes).
```

You can see the whole list: https://www.cryptocompare.com/coins/guides/what-is-the-gas-in-ethereum/

So, if you are using complex structures, the cost is multiplied.

Comment: So two bools, two unsigned ints, and an address cost over 30 USD every time you want to save or update them?  Am I misunderstanding how Ethereum works?

Comment: 30 USD seems to be so much even for that. Check the gas price and the estimated gas usage in solidity online compiler (https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/).
Are you running this smart contract in live net or in a private testnet?

Comment: What do you mean by complex structures? Do you have any example for a simple struct case? @KanekiDev

Comment: A complex structure may be for example: if you want to build a tree-structure in your smart-contract.